# How to implement 'replyingTo' and 'replies' associations on Sequelize model

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sequelize.js, model-associations

I have a model in sequelize for a post. I would like that you can retrieve both the replies *to* a post, and what post the post acting as a reply to.

In theory this just needs one foreignkey, a 'replyId' field so you have the table:

```
----------------------
|id|post     |replyId|
----------------------
|1 |post one |null   |
|2 |replying |1      |
|3 |replying |1      |
----------------------
```

And so to get posts replying to `1`, you look for `replyId` of `1`,
and to get what post `3` is replying to, you look for `id` of `1`

The sequelize relations are:

```
Post.hasMany(models.Post, { as: 'Replies' })
Post.hasOne(models.Post, { as: 'ReplyingTo' })
```

Then when adding posts to the db:

```
//Having created `post`
post.setReplyingTo(replyingToPost)
//Having found `replyingToPost`
replyingToPost.addReplies(post)
```

But whatever I try there is some sort of bug, like for example in the table above, where it is `null` you get id `3` and sequelize doesn't return any replies for id `2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem occurs because you want to hold two associations (`hasMany` and `hasOne`) on single field `replyId`. I suggest you use only single association, and the second one can be easily implemented via `instanceMethods`. Let me show you how it can be done

```
Post.hasMany(models.Post, { as: 'Replies', foreignKey: 'replyId' });
```

It creates one association on the field `replyId`, so we can now easily get/set replies of specified post. Now, in order to get the possibility of setting `ReplyingTo` on single post, we would have to add two instance methods on `Post` model.

```
instanceMethods: {
    getReplyingTo: function(){
        return this.sequelize.models.Post.findByPrimary(this.replyId);
    },
    setReplyingTo: function(replyingToPost){
        return this.update({ replyId: replyingToPost.id });
    }
}
```

So, the full example could be like that

```
Post.create({ post: 'post content' }).then((post) => {
    Post.create({ post: 'reply to previous' }).then((firstReply) => {
        firstReply.setReplyingTo(post).then((self) => {
            // now firstReply has replyId: 1
        });
    });
});
```

The query generated via `setReplyingTo` would be something like

```sql
UPDATE "posts" SET "replyId" = 1 WHERE "id" = 2;
```

On the other hand, we can also get the post to which given post replies to

```
firstReply.getReplyingTo().then((replyingToPost) => {
    // here we get the first created post
});
```

Which generates below SQL

```sql
SELECT "id", "post", "replyId" FROM "posts" AS "post" WHERE "post"."id" = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly! I guess its not quite in the spirit of sequelize, but i directly added a field to the model with the replyingTo username too so you wouldn't have to run getReplyingTo() each time